# webpack + Angular 2 (rc5) - components not rendering in production build

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack

I'm stuck on trying to get a production build working using WebPack with Angular 2 (RC5).

Following the starter project here
https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

I have been able to accomplish the following so far:

1. development build, running locally, live reload, etc no problems
2. production build with the caveat that my Abngular 2 components don't render.  No errors in the console (other than deprecation warnings)

So, on to the details.

Here is my *webpack.config.common.js*

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./webpack.helpers');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;

const METADATA = {
  title: 'Angular2 Webpack Starter by @gdi2290 from @AngularClass',
  baseUrl: '/',
  isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

module.exports = {

  metadata: METADATA,

  entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor':    './src/vendor.ts',
    'main':      './src/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {

    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json'],

    root: __dirname + './src',

    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],

  },

  module: {

    preLoaders: [],

    loaders: [{
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loaders: [
        'awesome-typescript-loader',
        'angular2-template-loader',
        '@angularclass/hmr-loader'
      ],
      exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
    }, {
      test: /\.less/,
      loader: "to-string!css!less"
    }, {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: 'raw-loader',
      exclude: [__dirname + './src/index.html']
    }, {
      test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
      loader: 'file'
    }]
  },

  plugins: [

    new ForkCheckerPlugin(),

    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),

    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
    }),

    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: './src/components/bootstrap/images/favicon.png',
      to: './assets/images/favicon.png'
    }, {  //TODO add using import?
      from: './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
      to: './assets/vendor/bootstrap.min.css'
    }, {  //TODO add using import?
      context: './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/',
      from: '*',
      to: './assets/fonts/'  //bootstrap hardcoded path to fonts one directory up from the CSS... >:
    }, {  //TODO add using import?
      context: './node_modules/ckeditor/',
      from: '**/**',
      to: './assets/vendor/ckeditor/'
    }]),


    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'src/index.html',
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),

  ],

  node: {
    global: 'window',
    crypto: 'empty',
    process: true,
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }

};
```

Here is my webpack.config.dev.js

```
const helpers = require('./webpack.helpers');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common.js');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const ENV = process.env.ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const HMR = helpers.hasProcessFlag('hot');
const METADATA = webpackMerge(commonConfig.metadata, {
  host: HOST,
  port: PORT,
  ENV: ENV,
  HMR: HMR
});

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {

  metadata: METADATA,

  debug: true,

  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',

  output: {

    path: __dirname + './build',

    filename: '[name].bundle.js',

    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',

    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js',

    library: 'ac_[name]',
    libraryTarget: 'var',
  },

  plugins: [

    new DefinePlugin({
      'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
      'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
      'process.env': {
        'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
        'HMR': METADATA.HMR,
      }
    }),
  ],

  tslint: {
    emitErrors: false,
    failOnHint: false,
    resourcePath: 'src'
  },

  devServer: {
    port: METADATA.port,
    host: METADATA.host,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    },
    outputPath: __dirname + '/build',
    proxy:{
      '/api/*': {
        target: 'http://analogstudios.thegreenhouse.io',
        secure: false,
        changeOrigin: true
      }
    }
  },

  node: {
    global: 'window',
    crypto: 'empty',
    process: true,
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }

});
```

Here is my webpack.config.prod.js

```
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');
const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const DedupePlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/DedupePlugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');


module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {

  debug: false,

  devtool: 'source-map',

  output: {

    path: __dirname + '/build',

    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.js',

    sourceMapFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].bundle.map',

    chunkFilename: '[id].[chunkhash].chunk.js'

  },

  plugins: [
    new WebpackMd5Hash(),

    new DedupePlugin(),

    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      beautify: false,
      compress: { screw_ie8: true },
      comments: false
    }),


    new NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /angular2-hmr/,
      function() {}
    ),

  ],

  tslint: {
    emitErrors: true,
    failOnHint: true,
    resourcePath: 'src'
  },

  /**
   * Html loader advanced options
   *
   * See: https://github.com/webpack/html-loader#advanced-options
   */
  // TODO: Need to workaround Angular 2's html syntax => #id [bind] (event) *ngFor
  htmlLoader: {
    minimize: true,
    removeAttributeQuotes: false,
    caseSensitive: true,
    customAttrSurround: [
      [/#/, /(?:)/],
      [/\*/, /(?:)/],
      [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/]
    ],
    customAttrAssign: [/\)?\]?=/]
  },

  //TODO needed?
  /*
   * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
   * Description: Node configuration
   *
   * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
   */
  node: {
    global: 'window',
    crypto: 'empty',
    process: false,
    module: false,
    clearImmediate: false,
    setImmediate: false
  }

});
```

Here is my home "view" HTML

```
<section class="as-view-home row">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-10">

      <h2 class="welcome-text-heading">Welcome to Analog Studios</h2>

      <p class="welcome-text-body">Welcome to the up and coming new version of the Analog Studios website.  We have a
        lot of plans in-store and a lot of great features for sharing music and representing artists.  Over the next
        couple of months, we'll be gradually updating the site with more and more content and interactions.  Please
        keep in touch with us through social media by clicking our links.</p>

      <p>Checkout our latest posts and upcoming events, below!</p>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

      <div class="posts-container">
        <as-posts-list></as-posts-list>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <as-events-calendar></as-events-calendar>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Here is my home "view" component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { EventsCalendarComponent } from '../../components/events-calendar/events-calendar.component';
import { PostsComponent } from '../../components/posts-list/posts-list.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.html',
  styleUrls: [ './home.less' ],
  directives: <any>[EventsCalendarComponent, PostsComponent]
})


export class HomeViewComponent { }
```

In the screenshot below, you'll notice that `<as-posts-list>` and `<as-event-calendar>` are DOM elements, but they have no content.  The static page text shows up fine, but not the components within it.  This also happens for my header and footer components (outside of `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`)
[image]

console errors I am seeing (just deprecation warnings)

```
vendor.0074bf4….bundle.js:1 NgModule t uses e via "entryComponents" but it was neither declared nor imported! This warning will become an error after final.
2016-08-24 10:40:36.707 vendor.0074bf4….bundle.js:1 NgModule t uses e via "entryComponents" but it was neither declared nor imported! This warning will become an error after final.
2016-08-24 10:40:36.707 vendor.0074bf4….bundle.js:1 NgModule t uses t via "entryComponents" but it was neither declared nor imported! This warning will become an error after final.
2016-08-24 10:40:36.707 vendor.0074bf4….bundle.js:1 NgModule t uses t via "entryComponents" but it was neither declared nor imported! This warning will become an error after final.
2016-08-24 10:40:36.707 vendor.0074bf4….bundle.js:1 NgModule t uses e via "entryComponents" but it was neither declared nor imported! This warning will become an error after final.
2016-08-24 10:40:36.707 vendor.0074bf4….bundle.js:1 NgModule t uses t via "entryComponents" but it was neither declared nor imported! This warning will become an error after final.
2016-08-24 10:40:37.000 vendor.0074bf4….bundle.js:1 Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
2016-08-24 10:40:37.006 vendor.0074bf4….bundle.js:1 The PLATFORM_DIRECTIVES provider and CompilerConfig.platformDirectives is deprecated. Add the directives to an NgModule instead! (Directives: n,n,n,e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e,e)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: are u spelling selector correct in the html and kindly post the errors in that are showing in console

Comment: I think the spelling should be fine, unless that what change from dev to prod build.  I will update to include the deprecation warnings and post-list.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in the new RC5 release. The only workaround at the time seems to be not to minify the build.

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618

Comment: thanks!  I've been following that thread and have been following up on a couple leads, including that one.  I plan on posting once I have everything working (dealing with other RC5 / prod build issues) and can validate against older versions of my code to figure out what exactly was needed (no `-p` flag, re-ordering components, and `keep_fnames=true` in the UglifyJS plugin)